# How do I get hidden folders to be listed in the Explorer navigation pane?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8

Currently, when I browse to, for example, `C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\`, the `AppData` folder will not be available in the Explorer navigation pane:

[image]

To my understanding, I have all related options enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable the hidden items option? Screenshot attached

[image: viewing hidden files]

Comment: Yep, that was it. I browsed to the folder directly through the address bar. Never thought about enabling the option :D Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Ribbon:

**View** → **Options** (on the right) &rarr **Change folder and search options**.

This opens a window Folder option:

**View** → Check radio button **Show hidden files, folders and drives**

[image]

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of the other answer?

Comment: No, it isn't. I submitted the answer and both have appeared

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept Pratyush's answer though, as he was slightly faster.

Comment: @PeterO. Im sorry then

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on **View** → **Options** → **View** → **Show Hidden Files, Folders, and Drives**.

[image: Options]